# Atomsphere + Jersey2 on embedded Jetty

Tags: java, jersey-2.0, embedded-jetty, atmosphere

I'm trying to get Atmosphere working with Jersey 2 on an embedded Jetty 9 server but I'm missing something. I've been going trough examples on https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere-samples/tree/master/samples (mostly jersey2-chat and embedded-jetty-websocket-chat) and I can make it so either websockets work, or jersey resources work, but not at the same time.

All I want are 2 resources: one with  WS & Jersey at /api/chat, and a 'normal' Jersey resource at /api/demo.

The init part of the app looks like this:

```
final ServletHolder apiServlet = new ServletHolder(AtmosphereServlet.class);
apiServlet.setInitParameter("javax.ws.rs.Application", AtRestApplication.class.getName());
apiServlet.setInitParameter(ApplicationConfig.WEBSOCKET_CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
apiServlet.setInitParameter(ApplicationConfig.ANALYTICS, "false");
apiServlet.setInitParameter(ApplicationConfig.ANNOTATION_PACKAGE, "com.resevo.arrow.athmosphere");
apiServlet.setInitParameter(ApplicationConfig.PROPERTY_COMET_SUPPORT, Jetty9AsyncSupportWithWebSocket.class.getName());
apiServlet.setAsyncSupported(true);
final ServletContextHandler wsContext = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
wsContext.addServlet(apiServlet, "/api/*");

final HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[] { staticResourceHandler, wsContext });
server.setHandler(handlers);
```

Does anyone have a small sample how to make this work?